# How to achieve something similar to C#'s await in AngularJS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I'm working on a project which requires me to enable my users to sign-in using Google for which I'm using the Google API client (reference for which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)).

Now my code is something like this.

**File: services/auth-service.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('gapi', function ($q) {

    var auth2;

    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '649922003965-ni9e6nad25dh3ejoll70va550kt7cu5u.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      });
    });

    return {
      isSignedIn: function () {
        return auth2.isSignedIn.get();
      }
    }
  });
```

**File: controllers/dashboard.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('DashboardCtrl', function (gapi) {
      alert(gapi.isSignedIn());
  });
```

Now the problem is that, when alert() command is ran in the dashboard.js file, by that time auth2 hasn't loaded (because it loads from the Google API via internet I guess) therefore I get an error that isSignedIn can't be called off undefined.

So what I would ideally need is probably something like a C# await function which waits for the value to be returned and them calls off it's method. Any solutions would be really appreciated. I've spent hours trying promises, and other approaches but I was not able to get any of them to work.

UPDATE:
Most of your answers would work in the scenario mentioned above. Let's try this scenario which is more complex and should've been mentioned in the first place. (Sorry for that).

**File: scripts/app.js**

```
.state('main', {
   url: '/admin',
   abstract: 'true',
   templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
   resolve: {
     check: function ($q, auth) {
       if(!auth.isSignedIn())
       {
          $q.reject({authenticated: 'false'});
       }
     }
   }
 })
 .state('admin', {
   url: '',
   parent: 'main',
   templateUrl: 'views/admin.html'
 })
```

Now, if I use promises here, angular wouldn't wait for the promise to be resolved. It would simple load the view and calling $q.reject after the view has been loaded will be of no use.

Comment: dosn't gapi.load() get 3 params?  the name of the module, the version and the callback? in that case gapi.load('atuh2', "1", function.....) should probably work.

Comment: @DenisBokor It gets two in the example mentioned on Google's website here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people. Problem isn't in the code not being right, the problem is in variables being populated in the wrong order :-)

Comment: You have included the Angular promise `$q` into your factory, have you tried combining that with the [GAPI listeners here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/listeners)?

Comment: @Asok I did try using $q but not with the listeners. I can't think of how. Can you please provide a small example so that I can understand what exactly should I be trying?

Comment: @haseebahmed7 kidOfDeath beat me to it, see below, that is something similar to what I was working up. I haven't tested it and not sure if MinusFour has the better answer. Best of luck to you sir.

Comment: @haseebahmed7 You could also use AngularJS `$broadcast` if, say, you had multiple controllers on a single page that needed to know whether or not the user was logged in.

Comment: @Asok I have updated the original post. Do check it out. Actually I don't need this in the controllers, I need it in the app.js file before the controllers for every page are actually loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using promises in this way:

File: services/auth-service.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('gapi', function ($q) {

    var auth2;
    var isSignedInDeferred = $q.defer();

    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '649922003965-ni9e6nad25dh3ejoll70va550kt7cu5u.apps.googleusercontent.com'
      });
      isSignedInDeferred.resolve(auth2.isSignedIn.get());
    });

    return {
      isSignedIn: function () {
        return isSignedInDeferred.promise;
      }
    }
  });
```

File: controllers/dashboard.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('DashboardCtrl', function (gapi) {
      gapi.isSignedIn().then(isSigned) {
          alert(isSigned);
      }
  });
```

Just change your isSignedIn function to return promise and resolve that promise when you have the value.

Comment: I've updated the original post, check that out and let me know if you think this would still work.

Comment: You are using promises in wrong way in your check function, you already have promise in this place, just return it: try this code `check: function (auth) { return auth.isSignedIn(); }`

Comment: No, I dont think that I'm using it the wrong way. That $q.reject which you see, is for the ui.router to stop the route and isn't related to gapi or auth.

Comment: Ok, I can see that now. I think that what you're trying to do is impossible because you are trying to make some asynchronous and possibly long running operation in the process of loading your view. Angular won't let you do that because it would be bad user experience if someone will want to navigate to some view and your page will still for few seconds because you are making a http call. You should design your application to make call to gapi before or after navigating to view. But this is all assuming that I understood your situation well, witch I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The feature is available on drafts for ES7, [babel](https://babeljs.io/) (a transpiler) has support for `async/await` if you feel comfortable with it. That being said, this can be done easily with just promises:

```
gapi.client.load(name, version, callback)
```

> Loads the client library interface to a particular API. **If a callback
>   is not provided, a promise is returned**. The loaded API interface will
>   be in the form gapi.client.api.collection.method. For example, the
>   Moderator API would create methods like
>   gapi.client.moderator.series.list.

The api already gives you back a promise, so no need to wrap it around `q`, all you need to do is return that promise:

```
return gapi.load('auth2').then(function() {
    return gapi.auth2.init({
       client_id: '649922003965-ni9e6nad25dh3ejoll70va550kt7cu5u.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    });
});
```

Now, from your controller:

```
gapi.then(function(auth2){
  //auth2 already loaded
});
```

**Edit:** Assuming you can get the returned promise on your check function. All you need to is:

```
var possiblyRejectedPromise = gapi.then(function(auth2){
   if(!auth2.isSignedIn.get()){
       throw new Error('Not logged in');
   } else {
       //LoggedIn
       return true;
   }
 });
return possiblyRejectedPromise;
```

Comment: Check my update and do let me know if you think this should still work.

Comment: I can't really answer the updated portion of your question. It seems that you are using `Angular UI`. If it behaves anything like the `$routeProvider` of Angular, then you can return a a rejected promise which will broadcast an error. I can't tell if it will stop the template from loading though.

Comment: yes I'm using ui.router. It works almost like $routerProvider and that reject does stop the actual page from the loading but the thing is, that reject never gets called because of auth.isSignedIn only has a promise and hasn't resolved it yet. Still, thanks for trying :-)

Comment: Why would `auth.isSignedIn()` return a promise? I can't tell what is `auth` is. All you'd need to do with the returned promise from `gapi.load(..).then(..)` is to add a new step with `promise.then(..)` that throws an error if it's not logged in (this will reject the promise).

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `await` in ES5. You need to get into the mindset of handling events as they happen and updating your application state based on those events.

For your specific issue, I believe you are correct in your assumption that it is failing because the `auth2` variable has not been set (and therefore is undefined). The "auth2 undefined" state is one of the application states that your code needs to handle. The solution may be as simple as changing your `isSignedIn` function like this:

```
isSignedIn: function () {
    return auth2 && auth2.isSignedIn.get();
}
```

This way it will only return true when the `auth2` variable has been set and the `isSignedIn` property is true.

Comment: "There is no equivalent to await in JavaScript" - ehhhh. ES6 supports generators, whose yield keyword can be used in a similar manner, and ES7 will support the async keyword. The ES7 might be a bit far off, but ES6 is here and ready to be used through Babel

Comment: I haven't gotten much into ES6 yet. Amended my post to reflect that, thanks.

Comment: The problem is, that auth2 is always available 1 second after the page has loaded. But to check if the user is allowed to view the current page or not, I need auth2.isSignedIn before the page is loaded probably in the app.js before my route is loaded. It can't be done with this.